# How to create a new request per row in table using karate DSL

Tags: karate

I'm able to manipualte the xml request (from a fIle) but I dont know how to iterate it over a table and form a new request for every row in the table

```
Scenario: Create subscriber base
    * table data
  | PaidMode| BillCycleCredit|BillCycleType|PrimaryOffer|SubscriberNo   |
  | '0'      | '100000'            |'1'        |'500033'    | Subscriber1   |
  | '1'      | '200000'            |'2'        |'410012'      | Subscriber2   |

* def Request = read('newSubscriber.xml')
* def fun =
"""
function(v) {

  if (v.SubscriberNo) karate.set('Request', '/Envelope/Body/NewSubscriberRequestMsg/NewSubscriberRequest/PrimaryOffer/Subscriber/SubscriberNo',v.SubscriberNo);

}    

"""
* karate.forEach(data,fun)
And print Request
```

From here I successfully print only one request :/ theres a whole lot I need to do (other webservice calls as an example)

Comment: The attached is to add lines to a current request, I'm looking to form a new request for every row in the table

Comment: Ahhh, the examples table actually does this almost perfectly, lol this can be left close